# Click cancel and ok doing the same thing in delete confirmation in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this one in js file

```
table = table + '<td class="td-problemlog-div-solution"><input type="button" style="width:40px;  color:White;  background-color:Red;" class="deletetButton" onclick="submitForm()" value="Delete" id="' + obj[i].PROBLEMID + '"/></td>';
```

It deletes selected row based on confirmation  .but here , click cancel and ok doing the same thing , delets the row

and here is the function

```
function submitForm() {
   return confirm('Rollback deletion of candidate table?');
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: I don't really understand what's happening here. Your onclick has submitForm() function, which simply returns true or false. Its not doing anything, so how can you expect a result?

Comment: It not hard to understand . But it shows me a  pop up and ok or cancel , when i click "ol" it deletes but when i click cancel , it still deletes .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onclick` will cancel the default behaviour (submitting the form) if there is a `return false` in it. if you cancel the `confirm()` you will return a false from `submitForm` to the onclick. but this means that the onclick function evaluates not to `return false` but just `false`. So essentially, you just need to do

```
onclick="return submitForm()"
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/4szSu/)

Comment: Thanks , it will work!

Comment: One question . how can i integrate return submitform()  in to that html part .Because i tried but it gives me error because of single quotes or double quotes

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help but you can use quotes and double quotes in strings by using a \ . example `var string="\""`  http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/zC3JT/